# uint32 array to float32 array, in place

Tags: c

I am working in a space limited environment. I collect an array of unsigned 32 bit ints via DMA, but I need to work on them as single precision floats using DSP extensions in the MCU. Copying the array is not possible - it takes up almost all existing SRAM. Is there a neat way to do this?

[Note] The data values are only 12 bits so out of range problems will not exist

Comment: What OS, CPU, programming language ?

Comment: Sorry! plain vanilla C

Comment: Just for completion, no OS, STM32F303x, Cortex M4

Comment: "Copying the array is not possible - it takes up almost all existing SRAM" what? you MCU has only 4 bytes of RAM?

Comment: I mean that the array is 16KB and the total space remaining is around 4KB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do it like this:

```
uint32_t a[N];

float *f = (float *)a;

for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    f[i] = (float)a[i];
}
```

Note that this breaks strict aliasing rules so you should compile with `-fno-strict-aliasing` or equivalent.

Comment: ahh he means to convert the uint32 *value* to float32 right? I though that he wants to convert the float value from raw binary in uint32